# Find and copy text between { and } in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a large text files which I want to copy all text between `{` and `sell/"}`. I tried using this.

`\{.*sell/"\}`

However, it doesn't find anything. I also hope that the copy process result into something like this:

```
{ .* sell/"}
{ .* sell/"}
{ .* sell/"}
```

and not this:

```
{ .* sell/"}{ .* sell/"}{ .* sell/"}
```

Can someone help me please? :x

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add sample text and the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

1. the text between and including the markers `{` and `sell/}` is on the same line
2. by copy you mean insert the text into a new file, keeping the original file as it is

the following would work:

1. copy the text into a new file:

   - we bookmark lines based on regular expression:

     - Choose Search -> Mark ... from the menu,

       - **Find What:** `.*(\{.*?sell/\}).*`
       - check **Bookmark line** and **Regular expression**
       - click **Clear all marks**
       - click **Mark All**
   - Choose Search -> Bookmark -> Copy Bookmarked lines
   - Create a new file
   - insert clipboard content with Edit -> Paste
2. Remove everything outside your markers present on the bookmarked lines:

   - we do a Find/Replace based on regular expression:

     - Choose Search -> Replace ... from the menu,

       - **Find What:** `.*(\{.*?sell/\}).*`
       - **Replace with:** `\1`
       - check **Regular expression**
       - click **Replace All**

As stated in the introduction: this will fail if your marker span multiple lines. The marking/bookmarking will only bookmark the first line and the *copy bookmarked lines* will only consider the  first line in that case.
(In that case we need another step that would condense the multiple lines block into a single line.)

Comment: It works amazing but it does have limitation due to Notepad++ crashing on large files. Although I did find a program that can manage larger files and use your method with success.

Comment: @Anti-Fun How big is large? I used notepad++ with fairly large files (several hundred mb). In the past, when I had problems with crashing Notepad++ it was often due to a plugin. Then I renamed the plugin directory in my user directory and tried if the problem was gone. Then I added plugin after plugin until I found the culprit. Sometimes updates of notepad++ or the plugin helped.

Comment: @LarsFischer  `(In that case we need another step that would condense the multiple lines block into a single line.)`   - nice of you to not include it, but mention it. lol.