# Notepad++ regex to get each unique number located between two recurring tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 16k lines of text in a file.
Opening it with `Notepad++`

Every few lines there is an occurrence like this one:

```
a few rows of text before
    Unique Identifier
    628612012-078
    Title
another few rows of text until the next Unique Identifier row
```

a few more lines of something else then it repeats again with a different number in between

```
a few rows of text before
Unique Identifier
1991-18613-001
Title
another few rows of text until the next Unique Identifier row
```

Picture of data:

[image]

What would a regex look like to get (copy/save) each id number located between each `Unique Identifier` and `Title` tag/row?

I don't mind if it deletes the rest of the text in the file or saves the output as another file or whatever. Ideally, I need to have just a list of those numbers occurring, in order.

Tried this/to adapt this [Find and copy text between { and } in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532927/find-and-copy-text-between-and-in-notepad) - couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the file has Unix(LF) line endings, the regex is

```
(?<=Unique Identifier\n).+(?=\nTitle)
```

then use Mark All and Copy Marked Text to get all mathes into Clipboard
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, after trying your example it says Mark: 0 matches in the entire file. The file is a simple .txt one - between each `Title` and next `Unique Identifier` there is another text that I need to ignore (if that is a problem?)

Comment: another text is not a problem, ensure the file is Unix(LF), see new screenshot

Comment: Never mind, double-clicked the place you highlighted and it changed to Unix(LF). Worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: in notepad++ you can switch the lineendings with rightclick on it in bottom panel

Comment: Yup, figured it out while writing the comment. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```php
^Unique Identifier\R(\d+(?:-\d+)*)(?=\RTitle$)|^(?!Unique Identifier$).*\R?
```

Replace with: `(?1$1\n:)` - first capture group value with line feed or nothing.

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Unique Identifier        'Unique Identifier'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \R                       any line ending sequence
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \R                       'R'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Title                    'Title'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        the end of the line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Unique Identifier        'Unique Identifier'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        the end of the line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \R?                      any line ending sequence (optional)
```

Comment: Thanks for the well-explained answer!